# Linux: run multiple commands without losing individual return codes?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I read [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260056/bash-multiple-command-on-one-line-with-different-exit-code), but my problem is that I have "plenty" of commands to run; and I need a solution that works for a systems calls.

We have an exit task that basically triggers a lot of "cleanup" activity within our JVM. The part I am working on has to call a certain script, not once, but *n* times!

The current implementation on the Java side creates *n* `ProcessBuilder` objects; and each one runs a simple `bash script.sh parm` ... where `parm` is different on each run.

Now I want to change the Java side to only make **one** system call (instead of *n*) using `ProcessBuilder`.

I could just use the following command:

```
bash script.sh parm1 ; bash script.sh parm2 ; ... ; bash script.sh parmN
```

Now the thing is: if one of the runs fails ... I want all other runs to still take place; but I would like to get a "bad" return code in the end.

Is there a simple, elegant way to achieve that, one that works with command strings coming from system calls?

Comment: Couldn't you just do something like
`bash script sh parm1 2>error.log ;  bash script sh parm2 2>error.log ; ...`

Comment: You can pass the output to one to the other.You can use pipe to pass the output to the next command.

Comment: I think he means something like this
`bash script.sh parm1 | bash script.sh parm2 | ... | bash script.sh parmN ; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"` I think this will give you something like `0 1 .. 0`

Comment: @GhostCat  Look at this one: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another

Comment: @Prabu Thanks ... I went for `set -o pipefail ; touch 1 | touch 3  ; echo $?` (using touch to have some indication that the steps did something) ... and that works ... so **-o pipefail** and using a pipe is what makes sense here. If you want to write that into a nice answer, I will go accept it.

Comment: You should consider learning full bash scripting. You need control structures and state variables which is quite tedious to do on the command line.

Comment: @GhostCat It's glad to know that helped you.

Comment: You can use variables there. And a proper `exit` with a status value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build up the return codes in a subshell as you go, then check them at the end using arithmetic evaluation.  E.g., on my test system (cygwin), at a bash prompt:

```
$  ( r=; echo "foo" ; r=$r$?; echo "bar" ; r=$r$? ; echo "baz" ; r=$r$? ; (($r==0)) )
foo
bar
baz
$ echo $?
0          <--- all the commands in the subshell worked OK, so the status is OK
```

and

```
                                        VVVV make this echo fail
$ ( r=; echo "foo" ; r=$r$?; echo "bar" 1>&- ; r=$r$? ; echo "baz" ; r=$r$? ; (($r==0)) )
foo
-bash: echo: write error: Bad file descriptor
baz
$ echo $?
1          <--- failure code, but all the commands in the subshell still ran.
```

So, in your case,

```
(r=; bash script.sh parm1 ; r=$r$?; bash script.sh parm2 ; r=$r$?; ... ; bash script.sh parmN r=$r$?; (($r==0)) )
```

You can also make that slightly shorter with a function `s` that stashes the return code:

```
$ (r=;s(){ r=$r$?;}; echo "foo" ; s; echo "bar" 1>&-; s; echo "baz" ; s; (($r==0)) )
foo
-bash: echo: write error: Bad file descriptor
baz
$ echo $?
1
```

`s(){ r=$r$?;}` defines a function `s` that will update `r`.  Then `s` can be run after each command.  The space and semicolon in the definition of `s` are required.

#### What's happening?

- `r=` initializes `r` to an empty string.  That will hold our return values as we go.
- After each command, `r=$r$?` tacks that command's exit status onto `r`.  There are no spaces in `r`, by construction, so I left off the quotes for brevity.  See below for a note about negative return values.
- At the end, `(($r==0))` succeeds if `r` evaluates to `0`.  So, if all commands succeeded, `r` will be `000`...`0`, which equals `0`.
- The exit status of a subshell is the exit status of its last command, here, the `(($r==0))` test.  So if `r` is all zeros, the subshell will report success.  If not, the subshell will report failure (`$?==1`).

#### Negative exit values

If some of the programs in the subshell may have negative exit values, this will probably still work.  For example, `0-255100255` is a valid expression that is not equal to zero.  However, if you had two commands, the first exited with `127`, and the second exited with `-127`, `r` would be `127-127`, which is zero.

To avoid this problem, replace each `r=$r$?` with `r=$r$((! ! $?))`.  The double logical negation `$((! ! $?))` converts `0` to `0` and any other value, positive or negative, to `1`.  Then `r` will only contain `0` and `1` values, so the `(($r==0))` test will be correct.  (You do need spaces after each `!` so bash doesn't think you're trying to refer to your command history.)

Answer (score 0):

A binary OR-ing of all exit codes will be zero (0) "if" and "only if" all exit codes are zero (0).

You could get a running exit code with this simple arithmetic expression:

```
excode=((excode | $?))
```

To run all parameters, you could use an script ("callcmd") like:

```
#!/bin/bash
excode=0
for    i
do     cmd "$i"
       excode=((excode | $?))
done
echo "The final exit code is $excode"
# if [[ $excode -ne 0 ]]; exit 1; fi     # An alternative exit solution.
```

Where this script ("callcmd") is called from java as:

```
callcmd parm1 parm2 parm3 … parmi … parmN
```

The output of each command is available at the usual standard output and the error strings (if any) will also be available in the stderr (but all will be joined, so the command "cmd" should identify for which parm is emitting the error).

Answer (score 0):

```
r=0; for parm in parm1 parm2 ... parmN; do
    bash script.sh "$parm" || r=1
done
exit "$r"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this

`bash script.sh parm1 || echo "FAILED" > some.log ; bash script.sh parm2 || echo "FAILED" > some.log; ... ; bash script.sh parmN|| echo "FAILED" > some.log`
Then check if there is some.log file.

|| - It's simple bash logical or ( executed if exit status of previous one is non-zero)

Comment: That is not what I want. I dont want to create some output file somewhere, to then check for its existence. (where the downvote is not coming from me)

Comment: This one should work like charm
`IS_OK=1; bash script.sh parm1|| IS_OK=0; bash script.sh parm2 || IS_OK=0; [ $IS_OK -eq 1 ] || false && true`